# Dispatcher BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, wpf

A question about Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

If I have a method as follows:

```
private void DoSomeWork()
{
   MyCanvas.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate
        {
            //Do something

            return null;

        }), null);
    }
```

And I call the method multiple times, then the multiple calls are executed in the order they are created as per docs: *If multiple BeginInvoke calls are made at the same DispatcherPriority, they will be executed in the order the calls were made.*  [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke Method MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx)

How does one clear this to stop another call being made or to reset the queue to just a single call?

Comment: You...don't.  At least not conceptually (there are ways in practice).  If you want to you probably should just use `Invoke` rather than `BeginInvoke` so you know whether you need to run each operation when you get to it.

Comment: If you know that multiple queues will be added up on dispatcher then at first place you should not call the method multiple times. Once the method gets called set some variable or something and based on it don't queue new items on dispatcher.

Comment: Why do you want queue items to the Dispatcher and then stop it from doing the items already queued?

Answer (score 1):

> How does one clear this to stop another call being made or to reset the queue to just a single call?

You don't. You don't get to control the dispatcher queue. What you *could* do is keep a count of "pending requests" (making sure you update it atomically, of course) and only execute if this is the last call in the queue (i.e. when decrementing the count gives 0).

Another option would be to keep some sort of timer for when the last call was made, and ignore further calls within some period of time.

If you could give more details about what you're trying to achieve, we could give more concrete help.

Comment: I'm basically working with a sort of stock ticker. My 'DoSomeWork' method creates the ticker and the dispatcher checks to see if the last node on the ticker is visible and appends the first to it etc. This works fine but I have a filter where a user can filter by positive/negative movement and when they do this, I rebuild the ticker by calling 'DoSomeWork' again with the filter applied. This feels bad as I was hoping to clear the dispatcher in some way. I probably need to go and read up a bit more on the Dispatcher though.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN link that you provided gave you the answer with a little more digging.

This operation returns a [DispatcherOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcheroperation.aspx) object that can be used to cancel. But, that is on a per call basis, as you cannot control the queue in its entirety.